# Can a SWF (using URLLoader) access HTTPS webservice?

Tags: ssl, https, flash, urlrequest

I have a fla (using ActionScript 3.0) I am compiling in Flash. I am using URLRequest and URLLoader to access a http webservice.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();     
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http:test.webservice.com");    
try {
   loader.load(request);
} catch (error:Error) {
   trace("Unable to load requested document.");
}
```

This works fine - however if I try and access a https address I get

```
httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=0]
ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://test.webservice.com"]
```

How can I retrieve data from a https web service? Does the SWF have to be hosted on a SSL secured page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install the flash debug player, you'll probably see the following in the log:

```
** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to https://www.example.com/service/ halted - not permitted from http://www.example.com/your.swf

Error: Request for resource at https://www.example.com/service/ by requestor from http://www.example.com/your.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.
```

By default a swf hosted in a http cannot access https --it's considered a different domain.

You'll need to set up the appropriate crossdomain.xml policy file, with care to verify the Content-Type is text/* or another whitelisted value. Additionally, you'll need a meta-policy file with "secure=false", which will allow https to be accessed from http.

```
  <allow-access-from domain="www.example.com" secure="false" />
```

Further reading:

[Policy file changes in Flash Player 9 and Flash Player 10](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check the crossdomain policy in the actionscript documentation.
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

> A secure server that allows access to movies hosted via a non-secure
>   protocol
>
> It is not advisable to permit HTTP content to access HTTPS content.
>   This practice can compromise the security offered by HTTPS.
>
> However, there may be cases where legacy Flash content is allowed
>   access to data of a HTTPS site. With Flash Player 7, this is no longer
>   allowed by default. To permit access to HTTPS data by Flash movies
>   served via HTTP, use the secure attribute in a "allow-access-from" tag
>   and set it to false.

```
 <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">


        <cross-domain-policy>


        <allow-access-from domain="www.company.com" secure="false" />


        </cross-domain-policy>
```

> It is saved as crossdomain.xml and placed on the site root of the
>   HTTPS server.

Comment: Some more information, or even a link would make this a much better answer.